# print row[3] out of a tsv file

Tags: python-2.7

I have some problems printing out row[3] of a TSV file. Hope someone could take a look and see what is wrong.

My code so far:

```
import networkx as nx

# Create graph
network_graph = nx.Graph()

path = []
with open('paths_finished.tsv','r') as tsv:
    paths = [line.strip().split('\n') for line in tsv]
    newPath = paths[16:]
    counter = 0

for row in newPath:
    print row[3]
```

If i make a print row, i get text like this:

```
['6a3701d319fc3754\t1297740409\t166\t14th_century;15th_century;16th_century;Pacific_Ocean;Atlantic_Ocean;Accra;Africa;Atlantic_slave_trade;African_slave_trade\tNULL']
['3824310e536af032\t1344753412\t88\t14th_century;Europe;Africa;Atlantic_slave_trade;African_slave_trade\t3']
['415612e93584d30e\t1349298640\t138\t14th_century;Niger;Nigeria;British_Empire;Slavery;Africa;Atlantic_slave_trade;African_slave_trade\tNULL']
['64dd5cd342e3780c\t1265613925\t37\t14th_century;Renaissance;Ancient_Greece;Greece\tNULL']
 ['015245d773376aab\t1366730828\t175\t14th_century;Italy;Roman_Catholic_Church;HIV;Ronald_Rea gan;President_of_the_United_States;John_F._Kennedy\t3']
```

Here i only want to take the links and put it in a list. The link you see here are for example this:

```
14th_century;Niger;Nigeria;British_Empire;Slavery;Africa;Atlantic_slave_trade;African_slave_trade
```

Then i have to put all those links in a list.
If i try print row[3] i get an error: list index out of range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you wanted:

```
paths = [line.strip().split('\t') for line in tsv]
```

or if the "\" is in the file, you want

```
paths = [line.strip().split('\\t') for line in tsv]
```